# nginx rewrite the last slash to no slash

Tags: nginx

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it.

I every slash at the end to redirect to no slash. So it must delete the last slash of the URL.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

This works, but only on normal URL.

If I have parameters like that `?page=2/` it doesn't rewrite to `?page=2`.

How can I fix that? My code does only work without parameters and doesn't help me here. I also looked already around but I haven't found something else.

Comment: Why *should* it work? The `rewrite` directive works on normalized URLs, while you seem to want to rewrite parameters. Note how in your example there is parameter `page` with value `2/`.

Comment: Yes but when i go to ?page=2, i am not on 2/, but if i go on ?page=2/ i stay also on 2/. So no one is redirected and i have duplicate sites, thats why i will redirect everyone to no slash at the end

Comment: Different URL parameters make for different URLs, right. But anybody can supply unlimited number of URL parameters. E.g. `/?page=2&blah=123`. What makes you worried about slashes in URL parameters? It is virtually pointless to attempt in redirecting based on slashes in their values.